# PHP NetSuite - Advanced Search with criterion

Tags: php, search, netsuite

I have PHP code for Advanced Search items in NetSuite,
but I don't know how I can combine to my search - filtering by item name.

My code is:

```
$service = new NetSuiteService($config);

$service->setSearchPreferences(true, $page_size, true);

$savedSearchId = '###';

$searchAdvanced = new ItemSearchAdvanced();

setFields($searchAdvanced, array('savedSearchScriptId'=>$savedSearchId));

$request = new SearchRequest();
$request->searchRecord = $searchAdvanced;
  
$results = $service->search($request);
```

I want to combine a criteria

Answer (score 1):

Here's sample code I found to get inventory details using Item internal id as a filter.  You can reference Suite Answer [90401](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/90401/kw/php%20search), [37585](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/37585/kw/php%20search%20filter), and [25066](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/25066/kw/php%20search%20filter).

```
<?php
require_once '../PHPToolkit/NetSuiteService.php';
$service = new NetSuiteService();

// formulate the criteria
$itemRecord = new RecordRef();
$itemRecord--->internalId = 140;
$itemMultiSelect = new SearchMultiSelectField();
$itemMultiSelect->operator = 'anyOf';
$itemMultiSelect->searchValue = $itemRecord;
$itemSearchBasic = new ItemSearchBasic();
$itemSearchBasic->internalId = $itemMultiSelect;
$criteria = new ItemSearch();
$criteria->basic = $itemSearchBasic;

// formulate the resulting columns
$searchRowBasic = new ItemSearchRowBasic();
$searchRowBasic->itemId = new SearchColumnStringField();      // Item Name/Number in UI
$searchRowBasic->internalId = new SearchColumnSelectField();  // Internal ID in UI
$searchRowBasic->location = new SearchColumnSelectField();    // Location (Main section of Inventory Item) in UI
$searchRowBasic->inventoryLocation = new SearchColumnSelectField(); // Location column in Locations tab (Inventory Item) in UI
$searchRowBasic->locationQuantityOnHand = new SearchColumnDoubleField();// Quantity on Hand column in Locations tab (Inventory Item) in UI

$columns = new ItemSearchRow();
$columns->basic = $searchRowBasic;

// item search advanced
$search = new ItemSearchAdvanced();
$search->criteria = $criteria;
$search->columns = $columns;

$request = new SearchRequest();
$request->searchRecord = $search;
$searchResponse = $service->search($request);

if (!$searchResponse->searchResult->status->isSuccess) {
    echo "SEARCH ERROR";
} else {
    echo "SEARCH SUCCESS, records found: " . $searchResponse->searchResult->totalRecords ;

}
?>
```